# Scrollable WebView without user interaction

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I want to embed a WKWebView inside my app (in only a section of the screen, not the full screen) and want the user to be able to scroll the webview within that section. However, I do not want any further navigation to happen inside the WKWebView - if the user touches anywhere (not scrolls), I would launch a separate SFSafariViewController. Can folks advise please what would be the best way possible to achieve this? I've tried the following approaches but coming across bottlenecks in each:

1. Use a flag that gets toggled in value when the delegate didNavigationFinish is called. Depending on the value of this flag, I override decidePolicyForNavigationAction to allow or cancel further navigation. So essentially once the web page is initially loaded (didNavigationFinish is called), further navigation is disallowed and I launch SFSafariViewController. However, this poses problems on websites with Javascript or where they have been routed via Google - the moment I create the WKWebView for them, didNavigationFinish is called multiple times and the flag value goes for a toss. Following code snippet...

   ```
   - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
           decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
           decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
   {
       if (self.allowFurtherWebViewsNavigation) {
           decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
       }
       else {
           decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);

           // Using a WKWebView category extension here with associated objects.
           [self launchSafariVCPostTapOnWebView:webView.underlyingURL];
       }
   }

   - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
           didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
   {    
       self.allowFurtherWebViewsNavigation = NO;
   }
   ```
2. I tried adding a (clear color) UIView as a subview of the WKWebView - whilst that prevents any user interaction on the web page, it also prevents the page from scrolling.
3. Finally, I tried making the WKWebView as a subview of a UIScrollView. That somehow blanks out the view completely!

Appreciate any inputs you'd have...!

Comment: Could you compare `navigationAction.request.URL` to the initial URL you are loading instead of using your `allowFurtherWebViewsNavigation`.

Comment: Thanks @Onato ... unfortunately I need the existing URL to also open in the new controller once it is initially embedded. So comparing the two wouldnt help....